# Sort by year as nvarchar and then numerically

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by, sql-convert

I have an `nvarchar` column that in essence stores the following data:

```
20-198
99-135
19-135
20-197
20-195
99-435
```

The first two numbers represent the year created and the last numbers represent the id of the unit made that year. Whenever I sort I get the 99's first and 19 last. I'd like to sort by latest year first and then numerically.

I have tried converting to `datetime` and using sub-strings but I cannot create a valid query and I'm not really sure where to go from here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Seems like you need to fix your design and split the value into 2 numerical data type columns. Normalise your data and you don't have the problem youre having.

Comment: you should edit to show the desired sort order - then show the sql you tried.  this would be easier with a better design - but you can be successful with substring manipulation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional logic in the `order by`:

```
order by (case when col <= '21' then 1 else 2 end),
         col desc
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you

Comment: I'd use `< '70'`, just for tradition's sake :)